# How to execute a SQL statement with SQL Server CE using a local database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, local-database

I am trying to insert a new record into a table (`HistQuote`) of a local database that I have set up. I am using SQL Server CE to create and execute my SQL statement. The table is made up of 8 columns:

- Symbol, data type: nchar(10)
- Date, data type: datetime(8)
- Open, data type: numeric(9)
- High, data type: numeric(9)
- Low, data type: numeric(9)
- Close, data type: numeric(9)
- Volumne, data type: numeric(9)
- AdjClose, data type: numeric(9)

But when running the code below I get the following error on the line

```
sqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery():
```

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 64,Token in error = Close ]

I am not sure if this is due to the fact that my parameters have a different data type then my table or something else.

thanks for your help.

```
object[] objSQLArray = new object[8];

using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(Settings.Default.DataStorageConnectionString))
{ 
    for (int intCurrentQuote = 0; intCurrentQuote < this.clbStockSelect.CheckedItems.Count; ++intCurrentQuote)
    {
        for (int intCurrentDate = 0; intCurrentDate < Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistStockDate.Count; ++intCurrentDate)
        {
            string strInsert = "INSERT INTO [HistQuote] ";
            string strColumns = "(Symbol, High, Low, Volumne, AdjClose, Close, Open, Date) ";
            string strValues = "VALUES (@Symbol, @High, @Low, @Volumne, @AdjClose, @Close, @Open, @Date)";

            objSQLArray[0] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistSymbol;
            objSQLArray[7] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistStockDate[intCurrentDate];
            objSQLArray[1] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistOpen[intCurrentDate];
            objSQLArray[2] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistHigh[intCurrentDate];
            objSQLArray[3] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistLow[intCurrentDate];
            objSQLArray[4] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistClose[intCurrentDate];
            objSQLArray[5] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistVolume[intCurrentDate];
            objSQLArray[6] = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistAdjClose[intCurrentDate];

            using (SqlCeCommand sqlCeCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strInsert + strColumns + strValues, connection))
            {
                sqlCeCommand.Connection.Open();
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Symbol", SqlDbType.NChar));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Open", SqlDbType.Real));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@High", SqlDbType.Real));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Low", SqlDbType.Real));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Close", SqlDbType.Real));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Volume", SqlDbType.Real));
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Adj_Close", SqlDbType.Real));

                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Symbol"].Size = 10;

                sqlCeCommand.Prepare();

                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Symbol"].Value = objSQLArray[0].ToString();
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = objSQLArray[7];
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Open"].Value = objSQLArray[1];
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@High"].Value = objSQLArray[2];
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Low"].Value = objSQLArray[3];
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Close"].Value = objSQLArray[4];
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Volume"].Value = objSQLArray[5];
                sqlCeCommand.Parameters["@Adj_Close"].Value = objSQLArray[6];

                sqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlCeCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I think the order of the parameters matters. Try changing the order of the parameters added to match the one in the query.

Comment: I have changed strColumns and strValues order but get a different error now _There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = Open ]_

Comment: from the error its the "open" filed that is failing. Is all the datatype mapping right, especially the datetime? Use Convert.ToSingle for real and Convert.ToDateTime for dates

Comment: I changed my code to use Convert.ToString() for the nchar field and Convert.ToDateTime() for the datetime field and Convert.ToSingle() for the real fields but get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open and close are reserved Words, enclose your column names in the sql statementin Square brackets:

```
[Close], [Open], [Date]
```